# How to use wifi communication for only one app

Tags: java, android, sockets, udp, android-wifi

I'm developing android applications which shows real-time data via UDP using WIFI connection on static IP addresses. I'm using AsyncTask class which is executed in one second period.

My problem is that the communication via UDP is interrupted by other applications (for example Facebook - ARP requests) because the WIFI is connected to the IP local device without internet connection.

The interruption is during execution method: `socket.receive();`

Is there a way to use wifi only for my developed application and has it disabled for other apps?

Comment: did you mean that the connection was lost and the device connects to another network?

Comment: Put your device in Airplane Mode, then active the Wifi. This disables your cellular data while keeping WiFi active.

Comment: I mean... the UDP is a Wifi network that you connect? Or it is an external IP that you call?

Comment: Also, UDP isn't interrupted - it has to share the signal transceivers and modem processor with other IP protocols, so you might want to work on filtering other packets rather than disabling them.

Comment: My android application is only receiving UDP unicasts from device (with real-time data) and this receiving delayed/interrupted by other mobile applications. WIFI connection isn't interrupted.